# Visual Studio Build Fails on Configuring SQL Server 2005

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, installation, setup-project

I'm trying to build a setup project in Visual Studio 2005, and it is failing every time, after opening a dialog box labeled `Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Tools` and configuring for a few minutes.  The `Microsoft SQL Server 2005 Tools` dialog then launches a dialog with the text `Failure creating local group SQLServer2005NotificationServices$COMPUTER_NAME`.  I suspect this failure is because I'm not currently local admin on my machine (a situation I hope will be rectified rapidly), but I don't see why I need to configure MS SQL 2005, as my project does not use it, and in fact has no DB connectivity.  How can I get past this step to a successful build?

**Related:**

- [Visual studio configures SQL 2008 on every build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201910/visual-studio-configures-sql-2008-on-every-build)
- [Visual Studio Setup and Deployment build fails with no errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847893/visual-studio-setup-and-deployment-build-fails-with-no-errors)

**Update:** Got my admin back, but this is still taking up time to run, and I'd still like to be rid of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found something about it on [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=113674). Seems like it's a bug. In the reply they linked to a knowledge base article with some [workarounds](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/329214/EN-US/).

Comment: Thanks, added that link to the page.