# Visual Studio 2015 automatically adding ItemGroup with service tag defined within

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nunit

For all of my .csproj files for unit test projects, the following XML block is automatically added to the .csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <Service Include="{82A7F48D-3B50-4B1E-B82E-3ADA8210C358}" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

What does this mean?, is it related to NUnit?

Comment: What more information do you want looking at the answers in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614342/what-is-service-include-in-a-csproj-file-for) SO question?

Comment: When seeing the 2 questions in my google results, this looked more like what I was looking for.  I sometimes think there should be an option to merge questions that are duplicates.  Often times, the "duplicate" is quite a bit newer, with newer/better answers.  A good percentage of the time the "duplicate" has both a better worded question and a better answer that was given before it was marked as a duplicate.  I would say this is true almost half the time.  Merging would also mean that search ranking would not matter cause all links would lead to the merged Q/A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is answered here: [What is "Service Include" in a csproj file for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614342/what-is-service-include-in-a-csproj-file-for)

In summary... it's how VS tags the file as a test project for it's own purposes.